# How to log mail client with Dovecot / Postfix

Tags: email, logging, email-server, log-files, dovecot

Does anyone know if it's possible to have Dovecot or Postfix output the mail client of a user? In Dovecot's variables list, I cannot find anything in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

In postfix you could use [header checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html), something like

```
/^X-Mailer:/    WARN
```

would probably do the trick. Note that this header is easily (and often...) forged or may not be present at all.